# Performing Iterative Calculations Of Distances in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, database, matlab

I need to perform calculation of distances between the longitude and longitude of one row in a  table with all other rows in the table.

The sample of the table is provided below:

---

```
temp_index, serial no, **id, date, longitude, latitude,** group ID

'8',  '2129163', '2', '733441.5634375',    '116.45479', '39.88098', '1'
'23', '2129164', '2', '733441.5646759259', '116.45468', '39.87086', '1'
'52', '2129165', '2', '733441.5669328704', '116.4581',  '39.88069', '1'
'70', '2129166', '2', '733441.5681712963', '116.4581',  '39.88069', '1'
'32', '2130837', '3', '733441.5652777777', '116.45595', '39.91784', '2'
'80', '2130838', '3', '733441.56875',      '116.44619', '39.90707', '2'
```

---

The constraint is that distances between rows having same ID should not be calculated.

Is there any query that I can use to execute this? I need to execute the queries via MATLAB.

The result should look like this: id1 and id2 are the id's whose distance have been calculated in the same table

---

tmp_index sn1   sn2 id1 id2 distanc grp_id1 grp_id2

'1', '2169736', '2133142', '31', '10', '0.4932', '22', '5'

'6', '2169736', '2187925', '31', '41', '0.12976', '22', '31'

---

Comment: Could you please post what should the result of the query look like?

Comment: @Mifeet I have put the sample result above. Thanks.

Comment: You first need to define what you mean by "*distance*" (approximations suitable in many applications are based on the [orthodromic distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance) with the Earth modelled as a sphere, but perhaps your requirements are more exact than that?).

Comment: @eggyal This is the formula that I have been using, I am converting each to radians first:                                    

diskm = 12742*asin(sqrtm(power(sin((latradians2-latradians1)/2),2)+ cos(latradians1)*cos(latradians2)*power(sin((lonradians2-lonradians1)/2),2)));

Comment: So then what's the problem?  Perform a self-join and apply that formula...

Comment: The problem is that I am new to Mysql and hence dont know how as to how the query would go...